# Does the lense for videos search youtube correctly

Tags: video, lenses

When I search in youtube.com for "Erika Tipo 11" I get videos about the actual show.

When I do the same using the Dash video Lense I get anything else except the actual show. I mean I even get chinesse stuff, some yoga lessons and anything VERY out there that is not even remotely related to the show. Now my questions are:

1. Does the video lense search in a similar way as searching in youtube/vimeo/any other video site?
2. Is there an option apart from the Filter settings to configure the behavior of the search so it searches in a similar way as one would do when searching from the actual site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Video lens [..] only supports YouTube Shows, Movies and Educations,
>   so most YouTube results won't show up in the default Ubuntu video
>   lens.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/alternative-youtube-video-lens-updated.html

Comment: +1 Nice one. Now one more reason not to open the browser lol.

Answer (score 0):

Video lens only give results related to YouTube Shows, Movies and Education.That is the reason for this problem.